# Understanding not equal in condition

Tags: c#

I have something like this where x can be any number from `1 - 8`. In this example we start with x equal 6  and that will return `TRUE` because it is not equal to `8` or `7`. Next example I have x set to `8` but that will also return `TRUE`. should this return false because it equal `Archived` which is `8` and I add the not equal `!=` sign. So my question is why are both returning `true`

```
    int x = 6;
    int Archived = 8;
    int Publish = 7;
    if (Archived != x || Publish != x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("True");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("False");
    }
    x = 8;
    if (Archived != x || Publish != x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("True");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("False");
    }
```

Comment: look up the difference between AND && and OR ||.

Comment: I find it a little incredible that someone who's had a StackOverflow account for _10+ years_ isn't familiar with boolean logic.

Comment: reposting the same question isn't going to change the fact that OR (||) returns true if EITHER or BOTH sides of the expressions are true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it is returning true on the second if/else block is because of the `||` operator that you use instead of `&&`. With the `OR` operator, as long as one evaluates to true it will return true.

In this case, `Archived != x || Publish != x`. evaluates to true because as long as one evaluation is true, it will return true.

If you changed it to:

`Archived != x && Publish != x` this would evaluate to false because in order for it to be true, both evaluations need to be true instead of just one.

Answer (score 1):

No, it should return TRUE because "x" is not equal to 8. You are checking if it is not equal, therefore it will return TRUE if it is not equal to 8.

Comment: but when I change x to equal 8 is still returns true

Comment: That is because you have an or (||) operator which checks if any one of the conditions is TRUE and returns TRUE if so. In the given example "Publish" (7) is not equal to "x" (6) therefore it returns TRUE.

Comment: what is x = 8 that will also return true

Comment: @Jefferson Read the above comment carefully.